# Typescript passing rest props to React component throws does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have written this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wise-router) which I use for some of my projects, and decided to upgrade to using TS.
The problem is that some of the props I pass in are all grabbed as `rest` props which then is passed to another child component. My component's prop types:

```
interface WiseRouterProps {
  component: React.ComponentType<any> | null | undefined,
  needsAuthentication: boolean | undefined,
  needsAuthorisation: boolean | undefined,
  isAuthenticated: boolean | undefined,
  isAuthorised: boolean | undefined,
  userPermissions: string[] | undefined,
  routePermissions: string[] | undefined,
  redirectTo: string | null | undefined,
  defaultRedirect: string | '/' | undefined,
  fallback: null | Fallback | undefined,
  debug: boolean | undefined,
  passRouteProps: boolean | string[] | undefined,
  rest: [] | null | undefined;
}
```

If I pass in a prop such as `exact` or `path` which are not used by my component, and are only passed to a child component as rest, I get an error such as:

```
Type '{ exact: boolean; path: string; key: string; isAuthenticated: any; needsAuthentication: boolean; needsAuthorisation: boolean; routePermissions: never[]; userPermissions: any; passRouteProps: boolean; ... 4 more ...; debug: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & WiseRouterProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & WiseRouterProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Which I think is logical, but I am grabbing every prop that is defined in my interface, and leave everything else as rest.

This is how I am grabbing my props including rest props:

```
const WiseRouter: React.FC<WiseRouterProps> = (props) => {

  const { component: Component = null, isAuthenticated, isAuthorised, needsAuthentication,
    needsAuthorisation, routePermissions,
    userPermissions, redirectTo,
    defaultRedirect = '/', fallback,
    debug = false, passRouteProps = false, ...rest } = props;
    //...
 }
```

I have been having this issue for some time now, and I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me. Thank you!

Edit: added code

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// Routes is an array of objects defining each route
<Router>
    <Switch>
        {Routes.map(route => (
            <WiseRouter
                exact={true}
                path={route.path}
                key={route.name}
                isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
                needsAuthentication={route.needsAuthentication}
                needsAuthorisation={route.needsAuthorisation}
                routePermissions={route.permissions}
                userPermissions={permissions}
                passRouteProps={!!route.passRouteProps}
                redirectTo={route.redirectTo}
                defaultRedirect='/'
                component={route.component}
                fallback={route.fallback}
                debug={true} />
        ))}
        <Redirect from="*" to="/http-status/404" />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Where are you rendering this WiseRouter ? . Please add that code as well . As the error states you are missing a prop called 'exact'

Comment: @Shyam thank you for your response!
it is rendered inside the Switch component from react-router-dom.

Comment: Can you add that code as well ? Looks like you are using the wrapper on top of Route component . React router dom should have a typing for Route component . So that in your code you can just do `type WiseRouteProps = RouteProps & YourCustomProps`

Comment: @Shyam Yes, correct. I have added the code :)

Comment: Shouldn't your component be called `WiseRoute` instead of `WiseRouter`? It's not actually routing, is it? Also, the parameters you cannot pass, are you passing them to the `component` prop? Do you know the types of routes you have? Because then you could do something similar as I have described in my answer.

Comment: WiseRouter take control over validation of user rights to access a specific route. So you are correct

Answer (score 1):

You can simply avoid this issue and pass everything by extening `Record<string, unknown>`:

```js
interface WiseRouterProps extends Record<string, unknown> {
    component: React.ComponentType<any> | null | undefined,
    // [...]
};
```

This means you will lose typechecking though.

So I would reccomend creating a specific `routes` property, and use it as generic so you don't loose that. I've assumed a lot and cobbled something together (even if it's not what you asked it was quite fun :D):

```js
interface MainProps {
  mainInfo: string;
}

const Main: FC<MainProps> = props => <p>props.mainInfo</p>;

interface AboutProps {
  aboutInfo: string;
}

const About: FC<AboutProps> = props => <p>props.aboutInfo</p>;

interface Routes {
  [route: string]: ComponentType;
}

const routes = {
  main: Main,
  about: About
};

interface RouterProps<T extends Routes> {
  routes: T;
  // [...]
  needsAuthentication: boolean | undefined;
  // [...]
}

class Router<T extends Routes> extends Component<RouterProps<T>> {
  public navigate<Key extends keyof T>(
    key: Key,
    props: ComponentProps<T[Key]>
  ): void {
    // fancy pants navigate magic
  }
}

function App() {
  const routerRef = useRef<Router<typeof routes>>(null);

  // Works:
  routerRef.current.navigate('about', { aboutInfo: '' });
  // Does not work:
  routerRef.current.navigate('main', { aboutInfo: '' });

  return (
    <div>
      <Router ref={routerRef} routes={routes} needsAuthentication={false} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, by doing `needsAuthentication: boolean | undefined,` you simply tell typescript that it bight be a bool or undefined. You will still need to provide `needsAuthentication={undefined}`. If you use `needsAuthentication?: boolean` you may actually omit the prop.

Check it out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-s2q4uc?file=index.tsx

Comment: Ah, after you added that new piece of code I see that this is not what you were talking about... welp

Comment: Haha, your piece of code has been very eye opening as TS is not yet my strong assets. Do you think I could for now just somehow have the errors ignored for such props?

Comment: @MurphyAdam I don't think that's the best option. Are you defining `Route`? Because I'm currently working on getting it to work for something like that. (I'm also not the best as TS, just have a little experience :D)

Comment: I agree it is not the best..or a good option as it renders typechecking's goal invalid. I just want to get into the actual functionality and have this take care of in the development of the package above. You can have a look at the full code of the package on GitHub https://github.com/MurphyAdam/react-wise-router/blob/master/src/index.tsx

Comment: Well consider the option that I've posted at the very top of the answer, this will allow you to pass pretty much anythign.

Comment: I tried that, but it throws other issues where I need to actually pass in a prop that is called `rest`, and thus a new issue as I can't get the other props as rest props

Comment: @MurphyAdam Okay don't think I understand your problem. Could you post a https://stackblitz.com as I did with as little code as possible? Like omit unnecessary props, skip wrappers that don't have to do with the problem, and so on.